# JMETER's Vusers memory keep on increasing

Tags: jmeter

I'm testing .NET application using JMETER, when ever I execute test with 300 vusers RAM consumption is more than 11GB. I also observed in JVisualVM that each vuser is taking more than 396MB, in fact its keep on increasing. Can anyone give solution how to execute with minimal RAM usage.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you followed https://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-and-tuning-tips? If not please follow that and try again.

Comment: Do you run it in GUI mode? In addition with plenty of memory consuming listeners being enabled? Is it the same if you switch to non-GUI mode?

Comment: what would be the memory consumption of single vuser in jmeter ??

Answer (score 0):

You are most probably load testing in GUI Mode using a [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree)

Use NON GUI Mode:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui

And read:

- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter_performance_tuning_tips/
- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html

Comment: what would be the memory consumption of single vuser in jmeter ??

Comment: It depends on the test plan, the responses , a lot of things.... You should accept this answer if ok for you and open another question on this for more details, this is how SO works

Comment: OK I agree. The size of my JMX file with and with out plugins are 9MB and 2.6MB respectively. My .NET application can only be accessed in Internet Explorer(I.E). Before launching application the size of I.E is 13MB. After launching application & performing required operations the size increased in this way, 20MB, 22MB, 55MB, 66MB, 72MB and finally after signing out, memory is 47MB. Can we guess the size of the vuser based on this data.